# How does matplotlib.pyplot.plot() connect scatter points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython

When we use `pyplot.plot(x, y)` in matplotlib, a line plot, which connects all the points (vertices), is drawn by default. I want to understand, exactly how does `plot()` do this? How does it connect the points? Does it use something like Bresenham's Line algorithm to accomplish this?

Comment: It draws line segments using the line drawing functions provided by the underlying graphics subsystems.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks for the comment. Could you point me to the function or module in pyplot that delegates to the subsytem?

Comment: You can dig down through the linked code as well as any of us.  But you may need to explain exactly why you need to know this.  There are many layers of code between the `x,y` points that you provide, and the actual pixels on the screen.  Most of us are content to know that if we say "connect (1,1) to (4,6)", the plotting program will know how to draw the appropriate line on the right figure.  We don't worry about how it fills in the in-between points.

Comment: @hpaulj I had to convert a collection of line plots (on the same figure) into an image array of Boolean values, where 0s would represent the background points and 1s, the connecting line. My initial idea was to use pyplot.plot to get the line plots and then, convert the final figure into an array, as pyplot.plt takes care of connecting the discrete points. But this seems suboptimal and so, I was interested in knowing how pyplot does this, so that I could use that directly, instead of a figure to array conversion.

Comment: _"…an image array of Boolean values…"_ OK but beware that the default backend is using antialiasing. ፨ An _idea_ could  be: draw the curves on your plot, turn off all the other elements (primarily spines) and save the figure to a bitmap format with the same dpi as your display (again, you'll have to deal with antialiasing)

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib doesn't do anything more than connect the points in the order they were given

You pass two arrays with x and y coordinates. Matplotlib takes the first point (x1,y1) and draws a line to the second pair (x2,y2), then from the second pair to the third and so on until the last pair

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,5,2]
plt.plot(x,y, 'ro-')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know, how it does it. A previous answer pointed me to the pyplot source, which I have already gone through. As DYZ said in his comment, pyplot seems to be wrap around the subsystem's functions, but I can't tell, where it delegates to those functions in the pyplot source code.

Answer (score 0):

If I `plot` two points, I get a list containing one `Line` object

```
In [58]: g=plt.gca()                                                                           
In [59]: g                                                                                     
Out[59]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7fce94a26400>
In [60]: g.plot([0,1],[1,2])                                                                   
Out[60]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fce94a26160>]
```

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D

That in turn has many attributes and methods, though a particularly relevant one appears to be a `Path` object

```
In [67]: aline._path                                                                           
Out[67]: 
Path(array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 2.]]), None)
In [68]: aline._path.__dict__                                                                  
Out[68]: 
{'_vertices': array([[0., 1.],
        [1., 2.]]),
 '_codes': None,
 '_interpolation_steps': 1,
 '_simplify_threshold': 0.1111111111111111,
 '_should_simplify': False,
 '_has_nonfinite': False,
 '_readonly': False}
```

https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path

Note its code types includes pen drawing directions like: `move to` and `line to`.  Graphics backends often take commands like: "put the pen at x", "draw line to y", "lift pen".  The backend takes care of interpolating the points between x and y, not the commanding code.  In that case the `edge` is not accessible to you.

While it doesn't use `matplotlib`, you might find the `turtle` graphics package instructive.  That lets you command a drawing `pen` directly.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

Comment: `turtle` is nostalgic to me. LOGO was where, I was introduced to programming. However, for my current problem, `Path` certainly sounds more interesting. Will look into it and update soon. Thanks.